# Friendly URLS / URL Rewriting using .htaccess on godaddy shared server

Tags: php, url, rewriting

I have been looking all over the place to find some code to work with my godaddy URL Rewriting, but no luck.

I am trying to make my website with Friendly URLS with .htaccess e.g.  domain.com/company/buy/items.php?fatherID=23  ==> into ==>  domain.com/23 I tried almost all codes and the best i got to is removing the .php

Sample Code:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

Turn mod_rewrite on

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ company/items.php?fatherID=$1 [NC,L]

Does anyone have any idea with some simple code? I am on godaddys shared Linux server.

I tried to redurect 404 error codes with:
ErrorDocument 404 /domain.com/home/404error.php
but this also did not work.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Remove/optionalize the leading `/` slash. And you don't have a use case for RewriteBase.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , it should be work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options -MultiViews      
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ company/items.php?fatherID=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried the code but it did not work. Is there something I am missing? I did not have a .htaccess file in the beginning originally. I also tried to clear all my web history and cookies

Comment: I think you didn't start up .htaccess file with    Options +FollowSymlinks

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy is a special case. It will work surely.

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 AddDefaultCharset utf-8

 RewriteEngine on
 Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes   

 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ company/items.php?fatherID=$1 [NC,L]
```