# .htaccess url rewrite does not work on GoDaddy Shared Server, Apache 2.4.3 - 404 error returned

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've created an .htaccess file. A test on madewithlove's htaccess tester (https://htaccess.mwl.be) said the URL rewrite is correct, but a live test returns a 404 error.

URL I want to rewrite:
http://example.com/folder1/folder2/word123 // To redirect to
https://example2.com/en/?key=word123

My .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN Part that is not working
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/(.*)$ https://example2.com/en/?key=$1 [R=301,L,NE]
# End part that is not working
```

I am using GoDaddy shared hosting with Apache 2.4.3-25. The WordPress lines work. If they are removed, then Wordpress Page and Blog links break.

I recognize this question resembeles [URL Rewrite keeps returning 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445502/url-rewrite-keeps-returning-404-error), but martoio redirected from an existing file.
I tried both Siraj Khan and Gautam Jha's solutions offered on [Friendly URLS / URL Rewriting using .htaccess on godaddy shared server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994375/friendly-urls-url-rewriting-using-htaccess-on-godaddy-shared-server) to no avail.

I'm at a loss for what to do, so your help is greatly appreciated.

This is the revised version after including neokio's suggestion:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN Part that is not working
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/(.*)$ https://example2.com/en/?key=$1 [R=301,L,NE]
# End part that is not working
```

Comment: I believe the 5th line ... `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` ... is redundant, or at least interfering with what follows. Try removing that, maybe it helps?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed the fifth line, and it is working the same. I will leave that line out because it does appear to be redundant. I also removed the [L] parameter afterward because madewithlove seemed to say it stopped processing at that point.

But a 404 error is still returned.

Comment: Thank you for the idea that something else might be interfering with the first, neokio. 
I started looking through my files and found an .htaccess inside the folder1. I deleted that .htaccess and the first one is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My .htaccess file, which was located in the public_html folder, base url, was being overridden by another .htaccess file located in folder1.

Check if an .htaccess file is located in a subfolder, because the .htaccess file in the deepest subfolder takes priority.